# FindByViewId returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, visual-studio-2017, ontouchlistener

I have a touch listener which listens in on a view in order to slide left/slide right

I pass the view(this passes the whole listview item) to the method then I need to grab the particular element I want to slide(the overlay)

here's the on touch event

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    {
                        this._downX = e.GetX();
                        this._downY = e.GetY();
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                {
                    this._upX = e.GetX();
                    this._upY = e.GetY();

                    float deltaX = this._downX - this._upX;
                    float deltaY = this._downY - this._upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        //left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0)
                        {
                            this.onLeftToRightSwipe(v);
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0)
                        {
                            this.onRightToLeftSwipe(v);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**And here's the slide method where sliderView is returning Null**

```
public void onRightToLeftSwipe(View v)
    {
        View view = v;

        Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this._activity, Resource.Animation.slide_left);

        View sliderView = v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_view_item_parent); //THIS RETURNS NULL
        sliderView.StartAnimation(slideLeft);
    }
```

This is the part of the layout which is relevant where v is the RelativeLayout and I am trying to grab list_view_item_parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">
    <Button
      android:text="Adjust"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
      android:text="Edit"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
      android:text="Move"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android.id="@+id/list_view_item_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000">
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

for now I have used a work around cycling through all the children for the view with only one child as the other view in the relative layout has 3 children... It's dirty, but it works in this case.  Still looking for a better answer though.

```
    public void OnRightToLeftSwipe(View v)
    {
        View view = v;

        Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this._activity, Resource.Animation.slide_left);

        View sliderView = null;
        int count = ((RelativeLayout)v).ChildCount;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            View v2 = ((RelativeLayout)v).GetChildAt(i);
            if (((LinearLayout)v2).ChildCount == 1)
            {
                sliderView = v2;
                break;
            }
        }

        //View sliderView = v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_view_item_parent);
        sliderView.StartAnimation(slideLeft);
    }
```